# My dropdownlist is on another asp page. Can I update it from my main page?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a weird(maybe?) situation where my main page updates Prefixes and after the user click the "button" I want the c# code to update the dropdownlist which is on another page.

Problem is the DDL is on another page so I can't reference the DDL ID which is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="PrefixID"</asp:DropDownList>
```

I used to have a DDL on the main page where the button was and it worked there but I decided to seperate the DDL to another page for a less cluttered interface.

@Chris - I enter in a Prefix like HJG and click the button to add it to a list like in an array. Yeah the Prefixes are stored in a DB. The prefixes are populated in a DDL on another page.

Comment: What is a Prefix? Are the Prefixes stored in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one page exists at a given moment during the serving of the user request. So I suppose that in the click handler of the button you are redirecting to the other page. And when redirecting you could send values as query string parameters:

```
Response.Redirect("~/otherpage.aspx?someParam=someValue");
```

and then in the Page_Load of the other page read the query string parameter value:

```
var value = Request["someParam"];
```

and update the dropdown list which exists on this page accordingly.

Comment: If I'm not redirecting the user to the new page (because the users just want to continue adding prefixes to the list) is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @DarinDimitrov's answer and Chris' comment: if the prefixes (preficies?) are in a database, why not just add them to the drop down in that page's OnLoad event?

1. Editor page contains form to edit prefix list
2. On post, editor codebehind or controller (MVC) updates prefixes in the database
3. Second page's Page_Load handler retrieves list from database
4. Second page populates drop down
5. Rendered page happily contains prefixes

Am I missing something here?